# Toshiba Satellite L645D screen brightness does not work on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, brightness, acpi, toshiba-satellite

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Toshiba Satellite L645D and the screen brightness does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: This http://askubuntu.com/a/214145/27968 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to edit your xorg.conf configuration. In a terminal, type:

`sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup`

This will make a backup of your xorg.conf file - just in case :) That being done, type:

`gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

and under **Section "Device"** add the following line:

`Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"`

Save and reboot.

Perhaps this already does the trick. In that case, congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late but I had the exact same problem with my girlfriend's computer, a Toshiba Satellite L645D with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I think this fix should also work on this computer model with other Debian-related Distros.

After searching and trying everything in the web I found this page:

[Keybinding to change brightness by way of acpi brightness file?](https://forum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=5997.0)

So what I did to fix the problem was open /etc/default/grub with nano (or whatever text editor you may like):

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

And search the line that starts with: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="(something)"
I don't remember exactly what text it had on the quotes. And make it look like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Then update the grub with:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Finally, reboot and that's it!
Hope that helps :D