# Brightness control doesn't seem to work on a Toshiba Satellite M115 laptop

Tags: power-management, brightness

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a Toshiba Satellite M115 laptop. The brightness control doesn't seem to work with the "brightness and lock" setting or <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f6</kbd> and <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd> (which usually works in Windows). How can I adjust the brightness and/or access different power settings, so my computer isn't running on full power all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my own issue by updating my BIOS. I did this by entering my model of Toshiba at http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/ and downloading the latest BIOS. Be sure to read all documentation that comes with the download before updating. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs says "Outdated and buggy BIOS firmware is a common cause of a variety of hardware issues (ex. intermittent wireless, suspend not working, and certain keys on keyboard not working correctly, kernel panics after plugging USB drive in)."

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with your particular model, but you can try some of these 'solutions'.

Add `acpi_backlight=vendor` to grub:

Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

You will find this line in the new opened window:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change it to:

Example:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

**Note your entry may be different - only add the `acpi_backlight=vendor`**.

After doing that, do:

```
sudo update-grub
```

---

If that does not get the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> keys working, you can do this via the system settings as seen below:

[image: System settings]

[image: Brightness and lock]

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions and neither worked. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @TempleOntherat - there may be something more significant than the Fn keys now working then. You may want to file a bug.

Comment: @cprofitt- Sorry, I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu. Would you post a link where I could read how to do that?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs says that before a person using Ubuntu files a report they should update their BIOS. I guess I should have done that first. Again, new at this.

Comment: @TempleOntherat - good find... if that does not help let me know. If you have IRC I can walk you through reporting a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for Toshiba Satellite L-750

open unity search and type "additional drivers"
select:
using NVIDIA binary driver -version ....
apply changes and reboot

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and the workaround I found is to use the following command in a terminal:

```
echo 300 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness > /dev/null
```

Change the 300 to adjust the brightness level. It is not an ideal solution but at least it gives some control on screen brightness.

There's a [bug report on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1069144). You may say that this bug affects you too if you wish.

Comment: the **bug** is for buttons that stop working after a suspend.

Comment: Yes it's true, but I've seen a similar problem on another laptop (no brightness control at all) where the workaround works as well.

Comment: this work around is the command line version of using system settings though; correct?

Comment: …when neither system settings nor shortcut keys work.

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: I tried your workaround and it said the command had an invalid argument. Not sure what that means. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` file?

Comment: Yes. After having done a little research, I'm beginning to think that my particular brightness/power management issue is related to the Phoenix Bios in my model of Toshiba laptop, which I hear is not a true Toshiba Bios.

Comment: Just updated the BIOS. Screen brightness feature in Ubuntu is now working. Thanks for your help. I think my issue is resolved.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Why don't you answer your own question to help others having similar problems?

Answer (score 0):

If like me these solutions don't work for you then try programming the keys. First install  *xdotool*:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Then open *Keyboard* from *System Settings* (Applications->System Tools->System Settings in Gnome).

Go to the *Shortcut* tab add press "+" to add the following shortcut:

```
Name: Brightness Up
Command: xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessUp
```

Click "Apply" then click on "Disabled" next to the new "Brightness Up" entry. Now press the key that corresponds to brightness up - *F3* for me, but possibly *F7* or something else for you.

Click "+" again and repeat the above steps to add the  following entry for brightness down:

```
Name: Brightness Down
Command: xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessDown
```

Now enjoy your brightness - or darkness if you are pressing the other key.

Answer (score -1):

try this to fix it. turn off computer, then remove battery and unplug the computer if plugged in. Now press and hold down the power on/off bottom for 15secs. This should reset your default computer settings, you will not lose anything on your computer. Now put battery back on and plug in your computer. Turn your computer on, hope this helped!

Matt Dang
NZ