# Ubuntu Screen Brightness setting not affect in Acer Aspire4750G

Tags: screen

I have Acer 4750G with Ubuntu 14.04 and the screen brightness is not affect to screen ( Not Decreasing the brigthness ). My VGA is nVDIA GEFORCE GT 540M, is that possible to decrease screen brightness ? how ?

Answer (score 0):

[Brightness control doesn't seem to work on a Toshiba Satellite M115 laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214129/brightness-control-doesnt-seem-to-work-on-a-toshiba-satellite-m115-laptop)

Have you tried the suggestions in this link. I have tried them and i managed to change my screen brightness through settings.

Answer (score -2):

Try this app, I am running ubuntu 14.04 on samsung np nc 110, nothing I tried worked even terminal solutions, until a came across this app, and it is free, though it does say buy in the app store, chillax, you should still get it free unless that changes!

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/brightness-controller/

P.S. Best of luck