# Function keys not working on Toshiba C-50-B

Tags: brightness, toshiba-satellite, function-keys

I purchased a Toshiba C-50-B-P-0010 about a week back, it did not come pre-installed with any OS. I have installed Ubuntu 14.04. The function keys are not responding properly. If i press F3 which is for brightness, it put the laptop to sleep! I have tried all the solutions suggested in the following link. One difference i observed after following all the suggestions is that i can change my brightness through my system settings. But the function keys are still not working as they should be. Touch pad on/off is also not responding.

[Brightness control doesn't seem to work on a Toshiba Satellite M115 laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214129/brightness-control-doesnt-seem-to-work-on-a-toshiba-satellite-m115-laptop)

I'm not very good at using the terminal, so please give detailed suggestions.
One of the suggestions is to update my BIOS, but the Toshiba India website drivers page doesn't have any BIOS for this model.

Comment: Check out this post in ask-ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/489247/14-04-asus-g56jr-fn-brightness-control . In my toshiba satellite I could at least use the xbacklight solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've just got a Toshiba C50-B-14D model. I was able to make most of the function keys working with the following procedure:

1. Make the `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/70-keyboard.hwdb` file with the following content (you will need root privileges to make the file):

   ```
   #Satellite C50-B
   keyboard:name:Toshiba input device:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svnTOSHIBA*:pnSATELLITE*C50-B:pvr*
    KEYBOARD_KEY_13c=brightnessdown
    KEYBOARD_KEY_13d=brightnessup
    KEYBOARD_KEY_13e=switchvideomode
    KEYBOARD_KEY_13f=f21                                   # Touchpad toggle
    KEYBOARD_KEY_158=wlan
   ```

   Note that it is important to have exactly one whitespace before the lines starting with KEYBOARD.
2. Run `sudo udevadm hwdb --update`
3. Run `sudo udevadm trigger` (This command would save you from restarting the machine, but if it doesn't work, try restarting the machine.)

After this the only key which do not work for me is the Wifi On/Off key.

To find more information on this process you can look e.g. [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=153157) or [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes).