# Some Fn keys not working in Ubuntu 22.04 on Toshiba Tecra

Tags: 22.04, keyboard, brightness, function-keys, toshiba

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my new Toshiba Tecra A50-K and some of the <kbd>**Fn**</kbd> keys do not work. They don't even register when pressed with the Fn command. Specifically the brightness keys <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>F7</kbd> and other keys like <kbd>F8</kbd>, and <kbd>F9</kbd>.

I have tried a lot of solutions available on the internet but none of them are working.

Comment: What is the debugging output you get from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6231/524752 ?

Comment: @DanielT It is not allowing me to post the entire output in the comment. It is the same as the one given on the link. Also, I don't know how this output will help solve the issue since the problem is not with the entire keyboard but only with these specific keys.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt install evtest` then `sudo evtest` and select your keyboard from the list. Then press the function keys and post what new output appears. Also run `xev`, press the function keys, and post the new output.

Comment: @DanielT When I press other keys, it detects the inputs but when I press the above-mentioned keys, there's no input detected. It does not even respond to the key press.

Comment: Then there is nothing Linux can do. Check in BIOS if something disabled those keys. Some keyboards also have a key to make lock keys or make the function keys do other things like brightness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I have created a cutomized shortcut using `xdotool`. I took help from the answer on this link https://askubuntu.com/a/305803/1017697 and have managed to add some more additional information here.

First find the keycode for brightness. This can be done by using `xmodmap -pke` with `grep` for keyword search

```
xmodmap -pke | grep -i brightness
```

This gives the output something like this:

```
keycode 232 = XF86MonBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessDown
keycode 233 = XF86MonBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessUp
keycode 237 = XF86KbdBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86KbdBrightnessDown
keycode 238 = XF86KbdBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86KbdBrightnessUp
keycode 251 = XF86MonBrightnessCycle NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessCycle
keycode 252 = XF86BrightnessAuto NoSymbol XF86BrightnessAuto
```

Now, go to settings and create a new shortcut with

```
Name: Brightness Up
Command: xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessUp
```

and map it to the `F6` key. Similar steps for brightness down.